# (High Sierra upgrade) sudden C++ standard lib errors

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line, linker, std

I'm trying to compile some code that worked before before upgrading to High Sierra.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/list:2276:23: error: 
      expected unqualified-id
        __m2 = _VSTD::next(__f1);
```

The line points to my `#include <list>` statement.

Google points to some similar issues and suggests changing the include dirs.

I tried `xcode-select --install` to install from command line as well as installed the Xcode Command Line `.pkg` from apple's dev center. Both didn't work.

I also read that the new dir for the standard lib isn't through the `/Application/Xcode.app` directory but now available through `/Libraries/` and I set the path to that using this command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

Still, I cannot seem to get my code to compile and the error still points to the `Applications/Xcode.app/...` path from before. (I have tried restarting)

Comment: This is going to be a code level debugging issue to find your linker errors. @ me or flag me if this needs to come back here for some reason after migration.

Comment: ok thank you for putting this in the right place

Comment: I think you'll get a much better triage and answer here. It's marginally on topic at Ask Different, but you'll get a lot of reinstalling Xcode rather than a razor sharp - "what precisely is the log past one line" from people that not only use linkers/compilers but write them.

Comment: Can you post a reduced test case?